# How to output values of R variables in an inline LateX equation in R Markdown (i.e. dynamically updated)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am unable to find a way to implement r code into an inline LateX equation in R markdown. The goal is to not have to hard code the values of my variable 'values' if they were to change.

Given:

```
values <- c(1.4, 2.5, 7, 9)
avg <- sum(values)/length(values)
avg
```

My current approach was to just copy and paste the values of my R variable into the LaTeX inline equation as such:

The average of $values$ is $\hat{v} = \frac{1.4 + 2.5 + 7 + 9}{4} = 4.975$

But this is cumbersome even with such a trivial example.

Using inline r code with `r values[1]` does not work inside of a LateX equation in R Markdown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

````
---
title: Inline LaTeX using \textsf{\textbf{R}} variables
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
# set variables

set.seed(1)
values <- sample(10:100, sample(3:5))/10
lv <- length(values)
avg <- sum(values)/lv
```

\begin{center}
The average of $values$ is 
$\hat{v} = \frac{`r paste(values, collapse=" + ")`}{`r lv`} = `r round(avg, 3)`$.
\end{center}
````

If you same that as a `.rmd` file and render it you should get something like

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks @Aksela

Comment: If you add a double $ and drop the period, in place of inline you get a stand alone formula (rendered a little bigger) and it pre-renders in RStudio.    


    $$\hat{v} = \frac{`r paste(values, collapse=" + ")`}{`r lv`} = `r round(avg, 3)`$$