# Markdown math formula from character string (RStudio knitr)

Tags: r, string, math, r-markdown, knitr

I have a character string variable (extracted from a regression model) that I would like to display as a math formula in a report using markdown in Rstudio knitr. For example

```
> formula
[1] "dGU ~ L(ec, 1) + dHH + L(dHH, 1) + L(dHH, 2) + L(dHH, 3) + dJKM + L(dJKM, 1) + L(dJKM, 2) + L(dJKM, 3) + L(dJKM, 4) + dTTF + L(dGU, 1) + L(dGU, 2) + L(dGU, 3) + L(dGU, 4) + L(dGU, 5) + L(dGU, 6) + L(dGU, 7) + L(dGU, 8) + L(dGU, 9) + L(dGU, 10) + L(dGU, 11) + L(dGU, 12) + L(dGU, 13) + L(dGU, 14) + L(dGU, 15)"
>
```

I know I can always manually type a math formula using markdown, but I would like to use whatever character string variable is returned by the regression model programmatically.

Comment: what do you want it to display? Cant it display what you have/

Comment: I am trying to display the formula in my report using the [LaTeX equations markdown style](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-syntax.html#math-expressions). As a fallback, I can always just display the character string itself in my report, but I would prefer the equations styling if possible.

Comment: Are the numbers subscription? Can you write the equation in latex and how it would look and paste the image in the equation

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to get it working using the tip from @bobloblawlawblog

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

Put this in your code chunk first:

```
fml <- formula(dGU ~ L(ec, 1) + dHH + L(dHH, 1) + L(dHH, 2) + L(dHH, 3) + dJKM + L(dJKM, 1) + L(dJKM, 2) + L(dJKM, 3) + L(dJKM, 4) + dTTF + L(dGU, 1) + L(dGU, 2) + L(dGU, 3) + L(dGU, 4) + L(dGU, 5) + L(dGU, 6) + L(dGU, 7) + L(dGU, 8) + L(dGU, 9) + L(dGU, 10) + L(dGU, 11) + L(dGU, 12) + L(dGU, 13) + L(dGU, 14) + L(dGU, 15))


md_fml <- function(fml) { # make modifications to formula
  Reduce(paste, deparse(fml))
}
```

And call this in markdown after:

Here is my formula:  **_`r md_fml(fml)`_**

Comment: I have used your first step to turn the string into formula class, but I am still struggling how to use either the string or the formula as an input into the LaTeX equations markdown style so the formula displays nicely formatted in my report. There is a link to the style I have in mind in my reply to @Onyambu

Comment: Sorry, I missed the backticks and formatting: \*\*\_\`r md_fml(fml)\`\_\*\*. It is basically inline r code shown here :https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-4.html  I did a quick search and found this answer, for better formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697684/how-to-output-values-of-r-variables-in-an-inline-latex-equation-in-r-markdown-i/55698210

Comment: Thank you, that last step allowed me to get it working. And I appreciate your "quick search" skills! I had been searching for over an hour before my original post.

Comment: Glad to be of help! I was just lucky with the search :)