# Incorporating a previously defined object into text block in LaTex file in R Studio

Tags: r, latex

I have a LaTex file in R where I have a code chunk that is calling a dataset and assigning the dimensions to an object. I want to be able to set the code to not evaluate so that I can put the variables into a text block that will show up in the pdf output.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do using a common R dataset.

The R chunk would look like this:

```
<<>>=
library(MASS)
data("crabs")
obs <- as.list(dim(crabs))
vars <- as.list(dim(crabs))
@
```

But I want this to not show up in the output, and instead have it show up as a text block that uses the `obs` and `vars` objects to create a sentence that describes the dataset.

Here is what I have tried without luck:

```
{\bf Dataset Dimensions}
``The crabs data set has \newcommand\x{obs[1])} observations
and \newcommand\x{obs[2])} variables.''
```

If is is working correctly, it should show up in the output as a sentence that says:

"The crabs data set has 200 observations and 8 variables."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following syntax works in .Rnw files for LaTex output to pdf.

```
\newline The crabs data set has \Sexpr{(obs[1])} observations and \Sexpr{(obs[2])} variables.
```

Answer (score 2):

In R markdown, you would still need to evaluate the code for these objects to exist, but you can hide the output in the chunks where you define e.g. `obs` by setting `echo=FALSE` in the code chunk options. Then you can use inline R code with a single backtick to reference the objects e.g.

```
The number of observations is `r obs[1]`.
```

If you need to do it inside a latex environment (although if you're just writing text  in r markdown you shouldn't need that to be in a latex block), it works the same way. See the responses in this post: [How to output values of R variables in an inline LateX equation in R Markdown (i.e. dynamically updated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697684/how-to-output-values-of-r-variables-in-an-inline-latex-equation-in-r-markdown-i) for including r variables in a latex equation.